# Shiny: Label position, textInput

Tags: css, r, shiny, styles

Lets assume I have a very simple application that only has 8 inputs grouped in 2 Panels (4 inputs | 4 inputs - see picture bellow) and based on these, I plot a small plot (easy peasy).

[image: The panel I want to make]

The problem that I face is that I want to have the labels only for the first panel, and on the left of the `textInput` box.

e.g.  (Please excuse my sloppy image editing!)

[image]

Any suggestion?

My MWE for Figure 1 output:

```
library(shiny)
ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  wellPanel(
    tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { max-width:300px; float:left;}'),
    id = "leftPanel",
    textInput("Population1000", 'Population 1000',"15"),
    textInput("Area1000",'Area  1000', "20"),
    textInput("GNI1000", 'GNI 1000', "2314"),
    textInput("GDP1000", "GDP 1000", "1000")
  ),
  wellPanel(
    tags$style(type="text/css", '#RightPanel { max-width:300px; float:left;}'),
    id = "RightPanel",
    textInput("Population2000", 'Population 2000',"15"),
    textInput("Area2000",'Area 2000', "20"),
    textInput("GNI2000", 'GNI 2000', "2314"),
    textInput("GDP2000", "GDP 2000", "1000")
  )
)
)
server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {NULL})
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi you can try to use Bootstrap's [horizontal form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal), look at the code below, it create 3 columns of width 4 each. You can change width in `class = "col-sm-4 control-label"` for labels, and in `width = 4` for inputs.

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(

      width = 4,

      tags$form(
        class="form-horizontal",

        tags$div(
          class="form-group",
          tags$label(class = "col-sm-4 control-label", `for` = "Population1000", br(), "Population"),
          column(width = 4, textInput(inputId = "Population1000", label = "Year 1000", value = "15")),
          column(width = 4, textInput(inputId = "Population2000", label = "Year 2000", value = "15"))
        ),

        tags$div(
          class="form-group",
          tags$label(class = "col-sm-4 control-label", `for` = "Area1000", "Area"),
          column(width = 4, textInput(inputId = "Area1000", label = NULL, value = "20")),
          column(width = 4, textInput(inputId = "Area2000", label = NULL, value = "20"))
        ),

        "..."

      )
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Result :

[image]

PS : you should not use same ids for inputs.

Comment: Hi @Victorp,  this is indeed a very nice solution, but it does not fix my issue, as I cannot group my entries in a panel - or something similar. Essentially, each column should represent a year (e.g. 1000, 2000) and as such, there should be a way to distinguish columns (e.g. a heading).  
(sorry for not making it clearer in the pictures. I will make the changes)

Comment: The easiest way is to put a label in your first input and add a line break in the label in the left. See the edits

Comment: Wonderful, tested it, and it works in a very nice way.